# jqコマンドが使えない

Tags: linux, shellscript

1.cliでvpcを作成する際にjqコマンドを使い,vpcid問題なく出力された

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2.DNSホスト名を有効にする際に問題があった
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
3.echo$vpcidで定義済みのvpcidが出力されるはずだが、何もなかった
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2):

> 1.cliでvpcを作成する際にjqコマンドを使い,vpcid問題なく出力された

これは変数`vpcid`への値設定ではなく、単に`vpcid=`の文字列の後にaws ec2以下のコマンド実行結果が表示されているだけです。

`1.cliでvpcを作成する際にjqコマンドを使い,vpcid問題なく出力された`の直後に

```
echo $vpcid
```

を実行しても`3.echo$vpcidで定義済みのvpcidが出力されるはずだが、何もなかった`と同じ結果になるはずです。

---

次のように、変数への代入とechoを分けて実行すればお望みの結果が得られると思います。

```
vpcid=$(aws ec2以下...)
echo $vpcid
```

Comment: 分けて見て無事に解決できました！ 本当にありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決できてなによりです。
スタック・オーバーフローでは回答横のチェックマークを押すことで回答を承認することもできますので、よろしければ承認をお願いします。